# Why the fetch() method is not working in my react app?

Tags: reactjs, twilio

I'm following this [tutorial](https://www.sanity.io/guides/guide-to-sending-sms-with-twilio-api). I think the `fetch()` method in `App.js` is not getting called.

Here's `App.js`:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const makeOrder = () => {
    fetch("/api/order", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: "Helllloooo!",
    }).then((response) => response.json());
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <h1>Markee</h1>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick={makeOrder}>
          Send
        </button>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here's `order.js`:

```
// pages/api/order.js
import sendSMS from "../../utils/twilio";

alert("happened");
const handler = async (request, response) => {
  switch (request.method) {
    case "POST":
      await sendSMS("xxxxxxxx", "Hooola!");
      alert("this happened");
      response.status(200).json({ message });
      break;
    default:
      response.status(405).end("This method is not allowed for this route.");
      alert("that happened");
  }
};

export default handler;
```

Here's `twilio.js`:

```
import twilio from "twilio";

alert("happened adda");

const accountSid = "xxxxxxxxxx";
const authToken = "xxxxxxxxxx";
const client = require("twilio")(accountSid, authToken);

const sendSMS = async (recipient, message) => {
  return await client.messages
    .create({
      mediaUrl: [
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1545093149-618ce3bcf49d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=668&q=80",
      ],
      from: "whatsapp:xxxxxxx",
      to: recipient,
      body: message,
    })
    .then((message) => console.log(message.sid));
};

export default twilio;
```

This is my first time writing a react app on my own. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I need more information to be able to help. Do you see this request coming out in your devtools? Also, isn't it a Next.js application?

Comment: I'd be surprised if `fetch` wasn't being called. What have you done to test that? Have you added a `console.log` statement before the `fetch` statement? Have you looked at the Network tab to see if the request is being made?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the problem turned out to be a mismatch between `"Content-Type": "application/json"` and `body: "Helllloooo!",`

Comment: You also aren't doing anything with the data you parse from the JSON in the response.

Comment: Or maybe it is the use of `alert()` in Node.js code (Have you checked the Node.js console for errors?)

Comment: @Quentin `fetch` is being called - i've tested it but it is not responding.

Answer (score -1):

Try with makeOrder(),

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const makeOrder = () => {
   alert("fetch called")
    return fetch("/api/order", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: "Helllloooo!",
    }).then((response) => response.json());
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <h1>Markee</h1>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick= 
    {()=>makeOrder()}>
          Send
        </button>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Still not working. `fetch()` method is not getting called.

Comment: edit didn't work either